# PromQL join a metric with a group left with another metric resticted by a boolean condition

Tags: promql

I need to join a metric m1 with a metric m2 where m2 is filtered, something like
m1 > on(...) group left m2 > xxxx

The above query returns mi timeseries joined with m2 but "> xxxx" is applied to value of m1 instead
of reducing the set of m2 timeseries
This could be a syntax
m1 > on(...) group left (m2 > xxxx) but, obviously  I get a parse error

Answer (score 0):

Just use parenthesis in order to properly set the priority of the second `>` operation:

```
(m1 > on(...) group_left m2) > xxxx
```

Comment: No, it does'nt work, the output is exactly the same, resulting timeseries contains m1 whose value is gt m2.value **and** m1.value is gt xxxx